# Click Listener not invoked within ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm extending a SherlockListFragment, but it should not matter as my question seems to be more general related to Fragments.

Now, I implement a simple click listener for my list, but it does not get called.

```
public class MyListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("debug", "single click");
             }
          });

          return v;
    }
}
```

Is anything wrong with this?

//Solution:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
        Log.i("debug", "single click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have a problem in that code. If you wish to get click events on the list rows then you should use setOnItemClickListener() and then pass it new onItemClickListener() object the same way you used the other method in your code. 
Hope this helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Hm there is neither a `setOnItemClickListener()` nor a `onItemClickListener()` which I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be as simple as returning the View you create, assuming you didn't simply leave that out for posting here. Do you see the list you are testing the click on?

Comment: edited above. yes of course I return the view. And I do see the list, and also can click on them. But the clickListener method does not get called.